# PHP pthreads, in pool tasks, ob_flush and flush cause crash

Tags: php, apache, pthreads, threadpool, flush

```
    $p = new Pool(10);

    for ($i = 0; i<1000; i++){
        $tasks[i] = new workerThread($i);
    }

    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $p->submit($task);
    }

    // shutdown will wait for current queue to be completed
    $p->shutdown();
    // garbage collection check / read results
    $p->collect(function($checkingTask){
        return ($checkingTask->isGarbage);
    });


class workerThread extends Collectable {

    public function __construct($i){
        $this->i= $i;
    }

    public function run(){
        echo $this->i;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
```

The code above is a simple example that would cause crash. I'm trying to update the page real-time by putting ob_flush();and flush(); in the Threaded Object, and it mostly works as expected. So the code above is not guaranteed to crash every time, but if you run it a couple times more, sometimes the script stops and Apache restarts with an error message "httpd.exe Application error The instruction at "0x006fb17f" referenced memory at "0x028a1e20". The memory could not be "Written". Click on OK ."

I think it's caused by flushing conflict of multiple threads when they try to flush about the same time? What can I do to work around it and flush as there's any new output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple threads should not write standard output, there is no safe way to do this.

Zend provides no facility to make it safe, it works by coincidence, and will always be unsafe.